# Upload não funciona online, aparece na tela parte do código da classe Upload

Tags: php, codeigniter, upload

Criei um projeto em *PHP* usando o *CodeIgniter* que faz upload de uma imagem para o servidor. Localmente funciona perfeitamente, porém, online, hospedada em um servidor da Locaweb (*Plataforma Windows*) apresenta um erro, quando vou fazer o upload aparece parte do código da *classe* `Upload`, o código fonte puro!

Não entendo, já olhei todo o arquivo e não encontro algum problema, mas vou continuar a procurar. Só gostaria de saber como isso é possível, o código fonte não deveria ser oculto sempre?

Comment: Isso vai depender da configuração do servidor, tem servidor que oculta os erros realmente, mas, tem servidores que isso ta aberto, talvez uma abertura de chamado resolva. Sobre o erro você pode colocar pra gente te ajudar é muito peculiar talvez um simples "." ponto resolva!

Comment: Valeu pela dica, descobri o problema, a classe Uplaod não tinha sido enviada inteira, ou seja, foi pela metade, o engraçado é que outros Upload funcionavam apenas este que não.

Answer (score 3):

Quando parte do código fonte é exibido na tela, significa que seu código possui a [short_open_tag](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) `<?` e no servidor essa diretiva está desabilitada. Para resolver isso troque todas as ocorrências de:

```
<?
```

por

```
<?php
```

Comment: verdade !!! o pessoal sempre faz com short_tag e isso pode ser o erro dele, bem lembrando.

Comment: Ainda bem que eu sempre foi convencional :), nunca usei short_tag.